# Open excel file using object model as different user

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an excel file that I'm trying to open using Excel object model (interop) with C#.
I want to open it as different user from the one who is currently logged in.
Something like:

```
Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.OpenAs(targetPath, username, password);
```

Any ideas on how (and if) it can be done?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? Are you trying to hide Excel from the current user? Anyway, it's far easier to process an Excel file using the Open XML SDK or a library like EPPlus. You don't even need to have Excel to do this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm trying to access an excel file that is located on Sharepoint site. the site has credentials for a specific user. I'm trying to open it from a C# application that uses interop

Comment: That's a *very* different question. How are you even going to download the file from inside Excel? Anyway, if the user is willing to give you his credentials (a very, VERY BAD IDEA for both of you, as *you* become liable for anything that could go wrong in the entire Sharepoint Site using those credentials), you can simply download the file locally, then open it. You still don't need Interop to work with Excel files though. Far better is to have the site's admin or the file's author give read permissions to your user's account, or read-only access to a guest account etc